# The notion of $\infty$ in calculus

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

According to calculus - an intuitive and physical approach(2nd) my Morris Kline 177p,

> $$\lim\limits_{r_1\to \infty} \frac {GM}{r_1}\tag{66}\label{66}$$
> We should note that we do not substitute $\infty$ for $r_1$. As we have previously noted, $\infty$ is not a number.
> As $r_1$ becomes larger and larger, the fraction in (66) must become smaller because the numerator is a constant. Moreover, because $r_1$ takes on values such as $10^6, 10^{12}, ...,$ the fraction becomes as small and smaller than any small quantity one may name. That is, the fraction must come closer and closer to $0$ in value as $r_1$ becomes infinite. Then
> $$\lim\limits_{r_1\to \infty} \frac {GM}{r_1} = 0$$

If $\infty$ is not a number then $\lim\limits_{r_1\to \infty} \frac {GM}{r_1} = 0$ should be written as $\lim\limits_{r_1\to \infty} \frac {GM}{r_1} = \lim\limits_{x\to 0}x$. Because $GM$ is divided by $\infty$ which is not a number so I think the result is also not a number. Is my thought right?

Comment: Do you know how limits are defined?

Comment: @Sandejo Thank you, I may just forgot the first principle.

Comment: The very idea of limit is to capture the ideal destination in terms of a determined value, and as such, it is precisely against the idea of using 'infinitesimal'. We want to bring the outcome of limit back to the realm of real numbers. (The very nature of real numbers and the notion of limit on it is designed to "forget" infinitesimals.) So, both concepts just do not get along well. However, it is possible to rigorously develop calculus using a number system that contains infinitesimals. In this case, the notion of limit is replaced by other machineries such as the transfer principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The limit of the gravitational potential, $GM/r$, is $0$ as the distance $r$ goes to infinity. In other words, gravity has no effect on an object infinitely far away from it. That is the physical thought process.

Mathematically speaking: Yes, $\lim\limits_{r_1\to \infty} \frac {GM}{r_1} = \lim\limits_{x\to 0}x$ because they are both equal to zero. However, when you say:

> ...$\lim\limits_{r_1\to \infty} \frac {GM}{r_1}$ should be written as $\lim\limits_{r_1\to \infty} \frac {GM}{r_1} = \lim\limits_{x\to 0}x$. Because $GM$ is divided by $∞$ which is not a number so I think the result is also not a number

this is **not** a very good way to think about it. In calculus, the concept of a limit is *the value of an input when its variable approaches a certain number*. Saying that $\lim\limits_{r_1\to \infty} \frac {GM}{r_1}$ is not a number would simply incorrect.

Comment: I think the reason I was confused is that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}f(x)$ has the number $0$ but $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ has $\infty$. The book explains $\infty$ means itself it gets larger and larger and I understood this as $\infty = \lim\limits_{x\to\infty}$. Then following thought was that "then is $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}$ the same as$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} = \lim\limits_{x\to{\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}}}$$\;?$" which is very unintuitive and strange thing. Now I think $\infty = \lim\limits_{x\to\infty}$ this equation is intuitive way to understand infinity.

Comment: I have only one objection: when you write, "Gravity has no effect on an object infinitely far away from it," I believe that you means "arbitrarily far away" instead of "infinitely far away." It seems circuitous to me to say the latter because in the first place, infinity is not a number, so what is the meaning of "infinitely far away?"

Comment: @opol, the statement "$\infty = \lim_{x \to \infty}$" does not make sense without an $x.$ On the other hand, the statement $\lim_{x \to \infty} x = \infty$ makes sense because for every positive real number $M,$ there exists a positive real number $x$ such that $x > M,$ e.g., $x = M + 1.$ In other words, no matter how large a positive real number you hand me, I can always find a positive real number larger than that. This makes precise the statement $\lim_{x \to \infty} x = \infty.$

Answer (score 4):

No. By definition, the statement $$\lim_{r_1 \to \infty} \frac{GM}{r_1} = 0$$ means nothing more or less than for every real number $\varepsilon > 0,$ there exists a positive integer $M$ sufficiently large such that for all indices $r_1 > M,$ we have that ${\left\lvert \frac{GM}{r_1} \right\rvert} < \varepsilon.$ Essentially, this gives a precise way to say that $\frac{GM}{r_1}$ is "eventually arbitrarily small and positive."

Put another way, pick your favorite positive real number that is very small, e.g., $\varepsilon = 10^{-9}.$ If it is known that $$\lim_{r_1 \to \infty} \frac{GM}{r_1} = 0,$$ then I can find a positive whole number $M$ sufficiently large (maybe $10^{10^{10}},$ maybe smaller) such that for all positive whole numbers $r_1 > M,$ we have that $0 < {\left\lvert \frac{GM}{r_1} \right\rvert} < 10^{-9} = \varepsilon.$